# How do I know if .ajax using Get or POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/treason.json?count=10&callback=?",

        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        },
        dataType: "jsonp"
 });
```

How do I know it is using GET or POST?

Comment: *'How do I know...?'* Check the documentation. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ `type` - Default: 'GET'. In general though, you can use the browser's console/network panel to see all of the HTTP requests (and their types) being made by the page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default it is **GET**

You can override it by specifying the **type** parameter value.

```
$.ajax({
         url: "someurl",
         type:"POST"
      });
```

You can also set it up globally at the [`$.ajaxSetup`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) method so that all ajax calls use that setting unless Override it.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  type: 'POST'
});
```

So if you do not have an `$.ajaxSetup` section where you are setting it, The answer for your Question is **GET**

Answer (score 0):

That's really simply, as the dataType is set to JSONP, and JSONP and cross domain requests inserts a script tag in the page to get the data, and as such it ONLY supports GET requests. POST requests aren't possible with a dataType of JSONP, so even if you specify POST as the type, jQuery will always use GET for those kind of Ajax calls, it's not possible to override that "feature".